# Controlling/Displaying/Sharing phone functionalities on a tablet (Wifi direct + Bluetooth)

Tags: android, bluetooth, tablet, transfer, phone-call

Here is the problem :
I would like to create an application on an Android wifi tablet that would be able to connect to an Android phone to achieve :

- Sharing contacts, SMSes
- Transfering incoming calls to the tablet
- Playing songs from the phone on the tablet (transfer the song then play it)
- A lot of other things but I think that this list will already give me some work...

Basically what I was thinking was :

- Using direct Wifi to pull contacts and SMSes on the tablet <- Should be ok, existing examples
- Using direct Wifi to transfer the music files to the tablet <- Should be ok, existing examples
- Using bluetooth to transfer incoming calls to the tablet <- **This is the hard part**

I know a bit about Bluetooth profiles and so on.
So what I want is expose the tablet on the Bluetooth network as a headphone device...

Basically, what I wanted, before going on to development, was if some people had experience with that and know if this can be realized.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that, because of the Blutooth profiles on tablets and smartphones, it might be impossible to connect them together and share such a thing.

It would require implementing new Bluetooth profiles in the tablet and/or phone lower layer code.